# android studio log cat automatically newline

Tags: android-logcat, android-studio-2.0

I use Android studio 2.0.
Logcat  show logs, but little bit odd.

I want to see one line. but it don't work.

Former Android studio 1.5 is show one line.

Please let me know how do that.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/26DCW.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

may be your soft wrap properties are enable.

Go to **File--> Settings --> Editor --> General.**

in General there is one option use soft wrap in editor.
just disable this option and try.. 
I think it works.

if it is not working then try this [image: Look image]
there is red circle just click at that property on once.. your problem will be solved.
thank you.

Comment: In 2023 this is still the correct answer